# Simulink S-Functions - Retrieve Initial Values from another S-Function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to model the respective processes of an internal combustion engine. My current modelling approach is to have different sub functions which model the different processes.

Within each sub function is a Level 2 S-Function which solves the ODEs to give the in cylinder state (pressure, temperature, etc).

The problem that I'm having is that each sub function is enabled depending on the current crank angle which is computed from the current timestep in Simulink. The first process works fine as I manually set the initial values, but then I can't pass the latest in-cylinder state (the output from the first sub function) to the second sub function to use as the initial conditions (it insists on using the initial values I set at the beginning of the simulation).

Is there any way round this? Currently I'm going along a path of global data stores, but haven't had any joy so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to solve this problem.
I'll show some of them as examples.

1. You can create additive output with `Unit dalay` block like this:
   [image: screen shot]
   So you can get value of your crank angle from previous timestep and USE IT in formula for solving you equations.

Also you can use some code like this:

```
if (t == 0)
    % equations with your initial values
    sred = 0;
else
    % equations with other values
    y = uOld + myCoeef;
end
```

2. Another idea: sometimes I use `persistent` variables in `Matlab function` to save values of some variable from previous step. But I think it makes calculation slower.
3. One more idea - if you have `Stateflow` you can create chart with two states: first for initial moment with your coefficient and second to solve new equations.

If I understood you in wrong way you can show your code and we'll offer some new ideas!

P.S. Example of my using of S-Function:
[image]

My S-Function needs 2 values: `Q` is calculated in simulink at every step, `ro` is initial I took from big matrix I loaded from workspace in table and took necessary value depending of time. 
So there is no any initial values in S-Function - all needed values I transmit into it from simulink!

Comment: Hi @Mikhail_Sam, thanks for your message, the issue I have is whether it's possible to pass new initial values into an MATLAB S-Function outside of the initialization function (or if it possible to run this initialization at some point after starting the simulation).

The overview of the model looks like this with the output of each sub-function going to a workspace array and global data stores.

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/B0G2WVn.png">

It sounds like Stateflow might be a way to go about if there is no way to implement the above?

Comment: Hi @ChrisLim ! can we transmit initial values like inputs to S-Function in your case? we can set number of inputs for S-Function = 2 (one for signal, one for initials) then calculate initial values in Simulink (or in Worspace) and will transmit it in S-Function at right moment. 
For example, I used this: create matrix of initials in workspace and load it in Simulink in `Lookup table` block and choose initials at each step depending of time.

Comment: The problem I have with that approach is that I don't know the initial value to pass to my second S-Function until the timestep that it is first enabled. 

I have found a workaround where I can reset the whole model (including S-Function) when the model is enabled though I don't think it's very elegant - I then have to pass in the values from a data store read outside the model due to the execution order.

Do you have any examples of your approach where you can pass the initial values to the S-Function outside of the Initialisation function? I can't seem to touch them in the main fcn body.

Comment: Hmm. I think I still don't really understand problem. we have 2 S-functions. when the first is enable it calculates initial values for second? So second works only after first? Can you show all scheme maybe? or clarify a bit it for me. by the  I'll show the way I used it in my answer - it's easy to show pictures in answer than in comment

Comment: So your model relies on the crank angle to calc? Why not use the crank angle as passed information in simulink?  Also you can check in each subfunction your inital condition and choose different approaches depending on it, you can also model if-conditions in Simulink itself, using switches with conditions (or just an if-statement in your s-function)

Comment: Hi Y.S and Mikhail, thanks again for your help. An overview of my model can be seen here: http://imgur.com/z2SdGlt

I have 3 enabled subsystems currently that are enabled upon a trigger function that tells each subsystem when to be active which is dependent on crank angle.

I've got past the passing initial conditions problem by resetting each subsystem when it is re-enabled using a unit delay which isn't very elegant. I hope this is a bit clearer with the image!

Thanks again for both your help.

Comment: It looks like your problem is in the left side - in your method of transmitting initials into your subsystem. or INSIDE subsystem. I can't see any problem at screenshot

Comment: Here's an example inside one of my subsystems: http://i.imgur.com/DAAD6Es.png

Currently, I'm using InputPort(5) to set the initial conditions (after the S-Function is reset when enabled). However, in the top model view, I have to use a unit delay to write to the cylinder condition or the read in this cylinder condition defaults to the initial values set at the beginning of the calculation.

Comment: ok. So, every time this system is enabled it takes this parameters: `engine geometry`, `start conditions`, `cylinder conditions` etc. So if NO ANY conditions inside S-Function it will use this inputs. You can change this conditions in Simulink and S-Function will work correctly. Why your S-Function always uses the same values?

Comment: The problem is that the S-Function solves the derivatives at each time step as an initial value problem. The cylinder conditions change at each time step and I want to use this as the initial values each time the system is enabled. However, I have to either use the values from the previous timestep (and not the latest) or it just sets them all to 0.

Thanks again for your help. Maybe if you send me your email in a PM or something then I can sent you the model files so you can take a look?

Comment: ok. I don't know how to write PM at SO, so have you Skype? i can give you my acc and then delete my comment with it

Comment: @ChrisLim we have a holiday now in my country, so I can connect with you later. But if you can find the way to expend your problem in your answer maybe someone else will help you!